# Is it possible to access data while a device is on bootloop?

Tags: boot-loop

I own a Samsung tablet (GT-n5110) and it is in bootloop. I don't have a data backup (yes, I'm an idiot). It isn't totally bricked, so I can access recovery mode (HOME+VOLUME UP+POWER), but before wiping it to factory configuration I am desperatelly trying to back it up. It isn't rooted.

I use linux (ubuntu), but I am open to trying to access it through Windows if anyone thinks it's easier (in spite both ubuntu and android are unix, right?). I've read in many foruns that it is possible to back up an android device through **ADB tools** in linux, but my device isn't recognized with `$ sudo adb devices`

I have alredy updated UDEV rules with the correct idVendor and idProduct and I have alredy reinitiated ADB server.

When I connect the device to the computer, it recognizes the tablet but says it cannot access it due to a MTP problem (this alredy used to happen before the bootloop, but it didn't bother me as I didn't use the computer to back the device up as I should have done). I have alredy installed and updated mtp-tools, but still receive the same message.

HERE IS MY MAIN DOUBT: IT DOESN'T WORK 'CAUSE I AM NOT CONFIGURING ADB CORRECTLY OR BECAUSE ADB CAN'T ACCESS A DEVICE ON BOOTLOOP?

Is there a way for ADB to recognize and access this device? Should I keep looking? Or is it simply impossible for a bootlooping device to be recognized though ADB or any other tools?

Thanks A LOT, I really need this help!

Comment: Was your debugging mode on before bootloop? Do you have custom recovery installed?

Comment: Unfortunatelly not, for both questions. I have the factory custom recovery, which does not have the option "backup and restore". Concerning debugging mode,  I am not sure and I am afraid it wasn't. I had adb alredy installed, so I might have activated debugging mode when installing it, but I really can't remember (never used it as I should have). It has crossed my mind that adb can't detect the device because of that.

Comment: (sorry, I had the factory recovery, obviously not the "factory custom recovery", as written above, lol). Also, I don't know if it's relevant, I couldn't update adb to the latest version, as the latest one available on ubuntu's repositories is 1.0.31. I've tried to update it manually but couldn't accomplish replacing the old executable files by the new ones, probably due to my lack of knowledge (I am still trying to do this as we speak).

Comment: If not a custom recovery, I do not see another option, since USB debugging was also not on. You could try installing a custom recovery using fastboot since fastboot does not require USB debugging to be on, but only if your bootloader is unlocked.

Comment: Ok, Dhruvil, thanks a lot! I am surely gonna try it (hoping my bootloader is unlocked), as well as the battery option suggested by user 157947 below.

Answer (score -1):

USB DEBUGGING CAN BE TRIGGERED BY PULLING OUT THE BATTERY...

If you have a built-in battery, You need to force a reboot by holding all the buttons on the device simultaneously for 30 seconds...

Try to remove the battery and replace it,   or force reboot ...

This will or should enable ADB Until boot logo starts to loop .. It will only enable it for enough time to check the settings and then disable it.... This means you can only run one segment of adb commands, So type them out first or just paste the following in CMD with ctrl+v

```
adb wait-for-device 
adb pull /data
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, user157947. I am gonna try it, as well as the custom recovery installation through fastboot sugggested above by Dhruvil. I have two doubts, here:

Comment: 1) Will recovery obtion "Reboot" work in this "force rebooting" option (I wonder it would work in a similar way than pressinf all the buttons, wouldn't it?) or is it mandatory to open the device? (Which I am willing to do if needed).

Comment: 2) As for the commands, if I obtain the reboot as needed I am gonna try it through linux. Is "adb pull /data" better then "adb backup -all"? When you say it will only enable it for enough time to check the settings, does it mean that once the connection stops the pulling of the data will also stop?